# Chrome (43.0.2357.81) JSON tree in network preview panel

Tags: json, google-chrome, networking, google-chrome-devtools, preview

Has anyone else noticed that Chrome's preview tab in the network panel now outputs json as a string (just as the response tab) rather than formatting it into a tree?

If so, can you point me in the right direction to get it solved?

Chrome version is 43.0.2357.81 m

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Do you set right content type header for the response?
For example, in PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```