# Chrome's Dev Tools displays network response preview as a string

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After a recent update (about a month ago), it seems that the **Preview** pane on the **Network** tab has quit rendering the response as a JSON object.  Instead it outputs the response as a string.  This was working as expected prior to the update.

[image]

We have been and still are sending the correct header type as suggested in this question - [Chrome (43.0.2357.81) JSON tree in network preview panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640783/chrome-43-0-2357-81-json-tree-in-network-preview-panel)

I've also found a few suggestions that this has been a problem in the past but alludes to the fact it was fixed? - [Google Chrome - Dev Tools - Network Tab - Preview - JSON vs. Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364120/google-chrome-dev-tools-network-tab-preview-json-vs-text)

I've posted to Dev Tool's Twitter account as well as submitted an email/bug with no further input.  Has anyone fixed this issue for *version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit)* or the previous version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this has been resolved as of Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (for Mac, haven't confirmed if this was an issue/solved for PC)

[image]

Comment: Not displaying as JSON object/tree on Preview tab in Windows 10 Chrome 61.0.3163.100 (with the correct header type sent: "application/json").

Answer (score 1):

The reason a JSON result set *might not* be handled as an object depends on how the JSON is formed. The result JSON string must use *double quotes* for keys and values for it to be parsed into an object.

In other words, return:

```
{ "msg" : "Success...", "numRows" : 23, "records" : [ { "name" : "Tony", ... ] } }
```

When my JSON result set stopped being parsed into an object, someone else had added JSON that used *single quotes* for keys and/or values.

```
{ "msg" : "Success...", ... , 'archiveMsg' : 'Using archive data' }
```

It took only one instance of using single quotes in the data structure to break the display. It still functioned properly in JavaScript, but I had no idea why the AJAX result JSON was now an unparsed string, instead of an object. Took a while to sleuth that one out.

Chrome and Brave are the only browsers I have tested this on.

Note: It is possible to return a header type of "application/json", but Chrome and Brave simply "pretty printed" the JSON structure. Not ideal, but it helped me limp along until I figured out what the real problem was.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that.  Most of the JSON data I worked with was serialized by a framework (e.g. Django, RoR), so I wouldn't think that would occur.  With hand-crafted responses, say in test data, that certainly could occur, especially w. IDEs having the ability to set preferences on linting.

Comment: I neither advocate or disparrage using frameworks in applications. I personally like to keep apps simple and spin my own very simple framework. If a framework is acting up, it is possible to spend days of time debugging things that are trivial  to deal with. Maybe it's overkill, but this approach works for me.